# Reverse string matching

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing, regex

So basically what I want to do is use a `grep`,`sed` or `awk` command (I'm not picky) that can do the following. I know how to go from `Vuln 1` to `OS1` but not vice versa.

Input:

```
test.txt 
Vuln 1
 OS1
 OS2
 OS3

Vuln 2
 OS4
 OS5
```

Output (heavy pseudocode):

```
$ grep "OS1" test.txt
Vuln 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is what you need:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; $h=$_ if $_=~/^V/; print $h,"\n" if $_=~/OS1/' test.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `perl -ne` reads the input linewise
2. `chomp` removes newline at the end (not necessary, but I think, it is cleaner)
3. The variable `$h` contains the content of the line, if it starts with `V`
4. `$h` is printed if the current line contains `OS1`

Comment: Is `$_=~/^V/` just a typical regex? I know almost nothing about perl, mostly a bash user.

Comment: yes, it is a regex. `$_` is the variable containing the line, the`=~` operator tells perl to evaluate the regex on the content of the variable. The `/` mark start and end of the pattern and `^` means that the pattern must match the start of the string. So in total `$_=~/^V/` evaluates `TRUE` when The string in `$_` begins with `V`.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution we use GNU AWK.

```
awk -F"\n" -v RS="" '/OS1/ {print $1}' test.txt
```

Explanation

- we take empty line as a record separator (`RS=""`)
- fields are separated by newlines (`-F"\n"`)
- the program is: if we find "OS1" in the record, print the first field (`/OS1/ {print $1}`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
grep -Pzo '\n?\KVuln 1(?=\n\s*OS1\n)' test.txt
```

- We are using PCRE (`-P`) and ASCII NUL as input line delimeter (`-z`) instead of `\n` so that we can match `\n` literally
- `\n?\K` will match an optional newline before our desired `Vuln 1`, `\K` will discard the match
- `(?=\n\s*OS1\n)` is the zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring that `Vuln 1` is followed by `OS1` in a `\n` separated line.

**Example:**

```
$ cat test.txt 
Vuln 1
 OS1
 OS2
 OS3

Vuln 2
 OS4
 OS5

$ grep -Pzo '\n?\KVuln 1(?=\n\s*OS1\n)' test.txt 
Vuln 1
```